# Azure Event Hub listening to blob changes

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer, azure-eventgrid

I have a use case where I have a streaming pipeline streams data into azure blob storage. I want to pick the data up from the azure blob through event hub, and configure the streaming ingestion into Azure Data Explorer.

I have try to create both event grid (blob storage) on ADX cluster, and the event hub namespace with one event hub pointing to my storage account, but I am not capturing the streaming messages into my event hub. The data format that I am working with is parquet.

Comment: Event Hubs connector in Azure Data Explorer to ingest data from the Event Hub into a table.Pre-processing blobs into a supported format (CSV, JSON) before sending to Event Hubs.
Implementing custom logic in the Function App to read Parquet data and convert it.
Exploring potential third-party connectors or extensions for Parquet ingestion.

Comment: Alternative Approach (Azure Stream Analytics):

Stream Analytics Job: Create a Stream Analytics job with Blob Storage as input and Event Hubs as output.
Parquet Handling: Within the job, use a custom query to process Parquet data (Azure Stream Analytics doesn't natively support Parquet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Below are detailed step-by-step instructions for creating an Event Hubs data connection for Azure Data Explorer and data up from the azure blob to event hub:**

- Create a storage account and select the events.

[image]

- Create an Event Subscription by selecting the Filter for Event Types, choosing Endpoint Type as Event Hub, and configuring an endpoint by selecting the event type.[image]

[image]

[image]

- Select  Azure Data Explorer cluster and database. Create a cluster and [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-event-hubs-connection?tabs=get-data%2Cget-data-2).

[image]

- Streaming ingestion must be configured on your Azure Data Explorer cluster.

##### Get Data

- Navigate to the **Azure Data Explorer portal**.
- In the portal, go to the **Query** section.
- Right-click on the database where you want to ingest the data and select **Get data**.

  [image]

##### Source

- In the **Get data** window, select the **Source** tab.
- Choose **Event Hubs** as the data source.

[image]

##### Configure

- In the **Configure** tab, fill in the required fields:
- **Subscription:** The subscription ID where the Event Hub resource is located.
  -   **Event Hub Namespace:** The name identifying your namespace.
  -   **Event Hub:** The specific event hub you wish to connect.
  -   **Consumer Group:** The consumer group defined in your event.
  -   **Data Connection Name:** A unique name for your data connection.
  -   **Advanced Filters:**

  - **Compression:** The compression type of the event hub messages payload.
  - **Event System Properties:** Additional event hub system properties.
  - **Event Retrieval Start Date:** The date from which existing Event Hubs events should be retrieved.
  - Select **Next** to proceed.

##### Inspect

- The **Inspect** tab provides a preview of the data. To complete the ingestion process, select **Finish**.
- Optionally, use commands to fetch new data or adjust settings in the **Command Viewer** and **Schema Definition File** dropdown.

  **Edit Columns:** Make adjustments based on your data type.

##### Mapping Transformations

- For certain data formats (Parquet, JSON, and Avro), apply ingest-time transformations in the **Edit Columns** window.
  [image]

[image]